# how to use abstract data types in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, types, python-requests

i want to know how the abstract data types works in python ! because my teacher gave us a project and said that we shall use it . we have to do 3 minors functions that we will use in the other 4 mains functions( the most important ones).

what i want to understand is this:
 -- the techer said if we used, for example , lists in ours minors functions the code should run well if he changes the interior of the 
 minor functions to tuples or dictionaires ( for example ) ... 
and i don t know how it is supposed to work , can u explain me ? give a simple example ?

Comment: Have you tried to do any research regarding this? Maybe consulting online tutorials and other materials?

Answer (score 2):

In object oriented programming, an abstract class is like a normal class that cannot be instantiated.

It's a way for the class designer to provide a blueprint of a class, so that it's methods have to be implemented by the developer writing a class that inherits from it.

Now, for Abstract `Data Types`, [according to wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type)

> An abstract data type is defined as a mathematical model of the data objects that make up a data type as well as the functions that operate on these objects. There are no standard conventions for defining them. A broad division may be drawn between "imperative" and "functional" definition styles.

As you can see, abstract pretty much means blueprints, not actual implementations, although in Java for example, an `Abstract Class` can have method bodies, i.e. implementation of the methods, just cannot be instantiated.

Furthermore, in Python, an abstract data type is one which you would make yourself.

Take for example a `list` and a `hashset`, they both form an abstract data type dictionary even though in python it would appear as a built in.

Abstraction is the technique in which you can make abstract data types or it can be viewed as a concept rather than a data type.

[More useful information on geeks for geeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/abstract-data-types/)

Comment: can u give a simple example please on how it works? like- if i do the functions this way (u exemplify the function )  and i call it on another function it should also work if i do the interior of the minor function this way ( and u exemplify it ) !